# Prettier error: No supported files were found in the directory

Tags: prettier

Prettier version: 2.0.4

When I run the command: `prettier -c src/**` I get an error: ***No supported files were found in the directory: "src/assets"***

In the directory, I have 2 files: **logo.png** and **loading.gif**. Also, I added **.png** and **.gif** to **.prettierignore**

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer:** just run `prettier -c src` instead.

**Explanation**

You didn't put quotes around the glob, so it was expanded by your shell, not by Prettier. Prettier ended up called like this: `prettier -c src/assets src/bananas ...`.

However, even if you used the quotes and the glob was expanded by Prettier, files like `logo.png` would be matched by the glob, and Prettier would complain it doesn't know how to format them. To fix that, you could make your glob more selective (e.g. `src/**/*.{js,css,html}`), but it's simpler just to pass a directory name to Prettier instead of a glob: `prettier -c src`.

See the [Prettier CLI](https://prettier.io/docs/en/cli.html) docs for more details.